# getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined in acivtiy extend fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, fragment

i am trying to implement maps in tabs of action bar. but to do that i need to change my FragmentActivity to Fragment. Now, to implement the google maps v2, i am not able to get the id of the map fragment.
Here's a code snippet from my code:

**xml file:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**java file:**

```
public class FragmentMap extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


public static class MapAct extends Fragment {

static final LatLng MARK = new LatLng(53.558678, 9.9271234);

    private GoogleMap map;
    MapView mMapView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addition, container, false);     
        return v;
    }

     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            map = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MARK));
  }
}
```

Please Help. I'm new to this concept.

Answer (score 3):

Yo need cast Activity to FragmentActivity

```
FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getActivity();
map = ((SupportMapFragment)activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is available in `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` from `SupportLibrary (appcompat project)`, which is located in `android-root\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`. If it's not available there, then it can be easily download from `Android SDK Manager` - "Extras/Android Support Library")